# Create a Preference that uses NFC in a dialog

Tags: android, nfc, android-preferences

I have a subclass of `EditTextPreference` that lets the user enter some structured text, and validates it before closing the dialog. I'd like to let the user enter this text by scanning an NFC tag while the preference's dialog is open. Scanning the tag would populate the `EditText` with the received text. Scanning the tag while the preference's dialog is not open would have no effect (i.e. it would let any other registered application handle the `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` `Intent`).

I have something very similar working in a related `Activity` already, so I don't need any help with the NFC part itself. The problem is wiring everything up through a `Preference`, when the NFC API is so tied to the hosting `Activity`, in these ways:-

1. `enableForegroundDispatch()` takes an `Activity` argument
2. the result is delivered via `Activity.onNewIntent()`

I have two ideas about how to proceed, with different shortcomings:-

1. Require that the `Activity` containing my `Preference` do all the setup for me. It would need to tell the `Preference` the `Activity`'s identity when it's first created, to allow the `Preference` to later call `enableForegroundDispatch` and `disableForegroundDispatch` at the right times. It would also need to forward `onNewIntent()` calls to the `Preference`. This seems pretty fragile - especially given that the `Preference` is usually going to be inside a `PreferenceFragment`, and the `Activity` needn't know anything about the individual preferences - but it would be more plausible if the `Preference` could find out what `Activity` is hosting it.
2. Stop being a `DialogPreference` and replace the dialog with a private `Activity` themed like a dialog. Creating the layout is no problem, and that would keep all the NFC-related code inside the special `Activity`. But then the problem is how to `startActivityForResult` from the `Preference`. Setting an `Intent` in the `Preference` is insufficient because that uses `startActivity` and doesn't have a mechanism to get the result back. Even if I do manage to `startActivityForResult`, I have the same problem as above, that that would be delivered to the `Activity` hosting the `Preference`, which makes the mechanism fragile again. If I could use some other channel to get the text out of the `Activity`, this option would be more suitable.

Can you help overcome any of these problems? Getting either alternative working is sufficient, but I'd prefer option 2 because it would help me with another similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this in the end with some tricksy use of intents. I started with option 2:

- I made my dialog into a new `Activity`, with a dialog theme. The new activity has all the NFC code: it passes itself to `enableForegroundDispatch`, and it has the `onNewIntent` method to update its text when a tag is scanned.
- Instead of using `setResult` to return its result to the caller, the dialog activity constructs an `Intent` with some identifying information, an indication of whether OK was pressed or the dialog was cancelled, and the new text. It sends the intent from `onPause`, protected by `if (isFinishing())`, to make sure the intent gets sent even if it's closed from an outside touch or the **back** key.
- I replaced my `EditTextPreference` subclass with a new subclass of `Preference`. The new class looks quite similar to `EditTextPreference` but doesn't need so much flexibility.
- My new `Preference` contains an anonymous `BroadcastReceiver` subclass which gets the structured text from the `Intent` it receives and sets the value of the preference, updating the GUI and triggering `onPreferenceChange` listeners.
- The `onClick()` method of my preference calls `getContext().registerReceiver`, passing the anonymous `BroadcastReceiver` and an intent filter that matches the identifying information set by the dialog activity. It then calls `getContext().startActivity` (**not** `startActivityForResult`) to start the dialog activity.

There's an extra complication: if a configuration change (such as reorientation) occurs while the dialog is open, the preference is destroyed and recreated along with its hosting activity. Because I used the activity's context, not the application context, to register the receiver, the old receiver will be unregistered, and the new preference needs to register a receiver. (Using the application context would have leaked the old activity and all its preferences, and would probably cause a crash when the old preference was updated.) So the preference has some more things to do:

- `onClick` also sets a flag so that it knows the receiver is registered. The receiver clears the flag.
- The preference's `SavedState` gets a copy of the "receiver is registered" flag.
- The preference's `onRestoreInstanceState` checks this flag, and if set, calls `getContext().registerBroadcastReceiver` with the same receiver and intent filter as before.

The result is that from a `Preference`, I can have the same functionality as a `startActivityForResult`, but all the code to achieve this stays inside the `Preference` and the `Activity` it calls: the containing `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment` doesn't need any code. As I have the same type of preference on several screens, this is a huge code reuse win, and of course much better encapsulation.

The same technique could be used for other preferences that want to use functionality that's hard to achieve in an `AlertDialog`, such as GL, video, sound, or embedding maps fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Go with 1) and create two interfaces:

1. A for receiving intents (or better refined NFC data like NDEF records etc)
2. B for setting or removing instances of A

Let the activity implement B and store A in a field. On an NFC event, call the interface if the A field is set.

Let the UI class implement A and store B in a field upon constructor.

And toggle nfc foreground mode based on whether the A field is an object or null.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am overlooking something obvious, it seems that implementing idea #2 should not be difficult.

You might want to take a look at the source code for [RingtonePreference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/preference/RingtonePreference.java) in the framework that calls `startActivityForResult()` from its `onClick()` method and process the intent it receives back as the result, very similar to your idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `PreferenceManager` methods used by `RingtonePreference` don't appear to be available to applications. (Specifically, that's `registerOnActivityResultListener`, `getNextResultCode`, and `getFragment`.)